# Browser behave differently on the same URL

Tags: php, html, browser

I'm writing a internet site. It is very simple, it is just index.php page, the change the content reading it from database (mysql).
In order to write the pages, I write them in a file, and than with php i upload in the database.

```
if (isset($_GET['insert']))
    {
        $f=fopen($_GET['file'].'.html',"r");
        $txt=fread($f,10000000);
        
        $str=$dbcls->escape_string($txt);
        $qry="INSERT INTO pages(id,page) VALUES (" . $_GET['insert'] . ",'" .$str ."');";
        $dbcls->query_command($qry);
        fclose($f);
    };
    if (isset($_GET['update']))
    {
        $f=fopen($_GET['file'].'.html',"r");
        $txt=fread($f,10000000);
        
        $str=$dbcls->escape_string($txt);
        $qry="UPDATE pages SET page='". $str . "' WHERE id=".$_GET['update'];
        $dbcls->query_command($qry);
        fclose($f);
    };
```

The  **fread($f,10000000)**, it is just temporary code.
The problem is that when I call the url:

```
localhost/?update=4&file=page4_funzioni_di_raggruppamento&page=4
```

that should update the page 4, with the content of the file "page4_funzioni_di_raggruppamento"  Chrome and Edge doesn't work, they start the search in internet ignoring the localhost, meanwhile Firefox run properly.
Meanwhile If I call the follow link, all three browser work.

```
localhost/?update=2&file=page2_tracciabilita&page=2
```

It is not a real problem since I can work with the one that works, and in production these instruction are going to be deleted.  I was just wondering if somebody can notice something that hinder these browser to work.
A second question, if I work with Firefox, once upload the css file it doesn't load it again if I update it. Somebody knows how to force Firefox to upload the css file at each update?

Comment: Are you including a protocol, are you are just typing `localhost/...` into the address bar?

Comment: _"Somebody knows how to force Firefox to upload the css file at each update?"_ - you mean _download_? Go research the keyword "cache buster."

Comment: Just typing the address. For the browser i solved using incognito mode